# No master volume in the new iPod Touch 5?

Tags: ipod-touch, audio, music, ios, sound-volume

I used to have an iPod Touch 3, then I upgraded to the latest iPod Touch 5 a few weeks ago. I noticed that there is no master volume. For instance, now, when I am just browsing Safari, and I change the volume, it changes the volume for "sound effects" (background noises from notification). But when I open a game or listen to music, and I change the volume, this is for "games/music". So the two volume sliders are different.

This is new to me, but I'm sure that some of you have experienced this before. Perhaps it even existed in the iPod Touch 4 that I skipped? Anyway, is there a way to get back the master volume method that used to exist, where one slider would control the volume for everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This separation of "sound effects" and "games/music" exists in iPod Touch 4 as well. There is no way for tuning a master volume on these devices. But you can set the "sound effects" volume as constant (`Settings` - `Sounds` - turn off `Change with buttons`) and pressing volume buttons will only change the "games/music" volume.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the best solution for now. I've muted the sound effects permanently since there will be times when I'm in a quiet area.